# problem with declaring variable in php?

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

i have a variables like $srange0 , $srange1, $srange2 $srange3.

i am using to declare some value to each value using for loop.

```
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
  $srange.$i = $i;
}
```

but its not working ?

is there any alternative solution for this

Comment: That a language provides a feature is not a valid motive to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
  $var = 'srange'.$i;
  $$var = $i;
}
```

**But**, whenever I see variables like that, I'd use an array instead.

Comment: I shouldn't even say this, but you can do `${'srange'.$i} = $i;`.

Comment: @konforce but sometimes dynamic variable names are very helpful if you know how to use them properly

Comment: @galymzhan, it is never helpful as a replacement for arrays. And in most cases, arrays suffice. Especially here.

Comment: @konforce sure, this code isn't perfect and suitable demonstration of dynamic variables

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
$srange = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; ++$i)
  $srange[$i] = $i;
```

For the purpose of this particular task, you can also do this:

```
$srange = range(0, 3);
```

That also builds the same array as my first code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The properway to add these dynamic variables will be like this

```
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
   $name = 'srange'.$i;
   $$name = $i; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you:

```
$srange0;
$srange1;
$srange2;
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++) {
       $range = "srange".$i;
       $$range = $i;
}
echo $srange2."<br />";
exit;
```